# How to make two QR code rendered same size

Tags: qr-code

There's two QR code in the page reference several dynamic input data, and data contains number, alphanumeric and Chinese(UTF8), and these two QR codes with same module width and error correction level(M), if data is below

```
QR1 = 0000|ABC|def|中文|
QR2 = aaa@bbb.com|     |XYZ
```

does any idea to make QR1 and QR2 will be rendered almost same size?
I try to make data of QR1 and QR2 with same length by appending space but no work :(

thanks

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]

I made those QR Codes at `www.unitaglive.com/qrcode`.

They have the same quantity of columns (that's is called the Version http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html).

What would you like to do exactly?